# set font size to UIActionSheet title

Tags: objective-c, uiactionsheet

I need to set size UIActionSheet title "Select option to Copy"

[image]

with this code :

```
  [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select option to copy:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"copy all ",nil];
```

Comment: What have you tried? How are you creating this action sheet? Show us some code ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take advantage of **Runtime Properties** to set the font. By using `NSAttributedString` you can achieve this.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"copy all ",nil];

//Creating Attributed String with System Font size of 30.0f
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Select option to copy:" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0f]}];

//Accessing the Alert View Controller property from Action Sheet
UIAlertController *alertController = [actionSheet valueForKey:@"_alertController"];

//Setting Attributed Title property of Alert View Controller
[alertController setValue:attrString forKey:@"_attributedTitle"];

//Displaying the Action Sheet
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

[image]

Comment: how can I change the font size of the blue buttons ?

Comment: @RoeiNadam There is no API to modify the fonts for action buttons inside actionsheet. That being said I would like to see if someone could come up with a solution for it.

Comment: Ok , it includes color of button title ?

Comment: you can change the color by setting `tintColor` property of ActionSheet

Comment: Or if you want different colors for each button then use `UIAlertViewController`. For each `UIAlertAction` there is a runtime attribute named `_titleTextColor`. Use this property to change color for each item

Comment: actionView.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];  not work for me

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala, according to UIAlertController there is no API to modify this. So, am I safe to use your solution when I submit my app to AppStore? Thanks

Comment: @ThihaAung yes you are safe to use this as these are the runtime attributes and the App will not be rejected. You can refer this https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala, is there any app that you use such feature?Please let me know?....

Answer (score 0):

You can change the title font of `uiactionsheet` by using this delgate

```
  -(void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {
        for (UIView *_currentView in actionSheet.subviews) {
            if ([_currentView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:_currentView.frame];
                l.text = [(UILabel *)_currentView text];
                [l setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:20]];
                l.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
                l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                [l sizeToFit];
                [l setCenter:CGPointMake(actionSheet.center.x, 25)];
                [l setFrame:CGRectIntegral(l.frame)];
                [actionSheet addSubview:l];
                _currentView.hidden = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it stiil not changing the size )-; I adding the Question

Comment: which ios version 7 or 8?

Comment: The view hierarchy has indeed been changed, and you should not be using UIActionSheet at all anymore in iOS 8 and higher. UIActionSheet is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet instead"